# imap_search() for unseen messages does not returning anything

Tags: php, email, imap, pop3

I am currently trying to get the UNSEEN/UNREAD messages from my server. Currently, I have this:

```
$openmail = imap_open($dns, $email, $password) or die("Cannot Connect " . imap_last_error());
if ($openmail) {
    /* grab emails */
    $emails = imap_search($openmail, 'UNSEEN');
    if ($emails) {
        //For every e-mail.
        $tot = imap_num_msg($openmail);
        for ($i = $tot; $i > 0; $i--) {
            $structure = imap_fetchstructure($openmail, $i);
            if (isset($structure->parts) && is_array($structure->parts) && isset($structure->parts[1])) {
                $part = $structure->parts[1];
                $message = imap_fetchbody($openmail, $i, 2, FT_PEEK);

                if ($part->encoding == 3) {
                    $message = imap_base64($message);
                } else if ($part->encoding == 1) {
                    $message = imap_8bit($message);
                } else {
                    $message = imap_qprint($message);
                }
            }
            $header = imap_header($openmail, $i);
            $from = imap_utf8($header->fromaddress);
            $subject = $header->Subject;
            $subject = substr($subject, 0, 150);
            $date = $header->Date;
        }
        /* Print out the Unseen messages in here! */
    } else {
        /* No unseen messages */
        echo "No unseen";
    }
}
```

I've tried sending multiply emails to my mailserver, refreshed the page with the above script. But I keep getting the "No unseen".

I've tried to output the `$emails` but it's empty. It can't find anything.

If I try to just get ALL the messages (no unseen filter), I can see the emails I've sent to the mailbox, although, they're all marked as read.

Comment: Is your mail client running? Do you get the same results for `UNREAD`?

Comment: Well, as I can connect fine via my $openmail variable, Its running. I can also get all emails, just not get the "UNSEEN" ones. Using "UNREAD" instead of "UNSEEN" doesn't change anything.

Comment: Try grabbing information about some of the mails you expect to show up in your search with `imap_headerinfo()` and check if they are actually flagged as unread/unseen.

Comment: They're not. The [UNSEEN] is empty. I believe it may happen when I refresh the page. Please see my edited question, for full code. I have added code after the `for(){`

Comment: Fetching a part of the message (even just the subject) sets the \seen flag, so what's why your messages stop being unseen. If you want an actual answr I'm afraid you'll have to post the imap commands used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code `$message = imap_fetchbody($openmail, $i, 2, FT_PEEK);` uses hardcoded part offsets, i.e. it assumes that a message is always `multipart/alternative` with `text/plain` and `text/html`. That's a very wrong assumption.

You have to look at the output of the `BODYSTRUCTURE` to see what the MIME structure of your mail is.

With that out of the way, be sure that none of your commands use the `BODY` fetch operation; you have to use `BODY.PEEK`. I have no idea how this is accessible within the PHP c-client bindings.